# Using Google Analytics to track events

Tags: civievent

We'd like to set up goals inside CiviCRM regarding people signing up for events. How would you go about doing that? I'm not sure what URL we would use for them.

Our events use price sets; take payments via Paypal or pay later (send check or call in with credit card info).

Drupal CMS. Currently it's on Civi 4.7.22, but we'll be upgrading to the lastest version soon.

UPDATE: Has there been any progress on this? It really seems odd that there doesn't seem to be a way to track conversions in CiviCRM. The only thing I've been pointed to is something that is 3 years old and therefore unlikely to work with the current CiviCRM.

Comment: Does no one keep track of things like event sign-ups in their Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

There was some work done on CiviCRM integration with Google Analytics as a part of Google Summer of Code program.
This should be a good base. Check https://civicrm.org/blog/vishalagarwal/gsoc-completion-report-on-integrating-google-analytics-with-civicrm

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that maybe there was a URL we could use with wildcards or something along that line. It's how most systems seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if to know what platforms you use (what cms and version of Civi) and how precise you need your tracking to be - however I can share that on one of my sites - we use wordpress and Civi.  On Wordpress we use the plugin Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP) which embeds analytics all over our site. (you do not need this plugin to have analytics on your site - we just found it super easy) When visiting analytics.google.com we are able to see all the analytics it offers for all of our CiviCRM pages, including events. We are able to see how many people visited an event page, then went to registration page, then went to confirmation page, etc. However there is no way to see who exactly did what and google analytics will not track users that are blocking cookies, though that is a small amount of people.

Here is an example of a small event and the analytics we have from it. Is this the type of stuff you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: We need to be able to track conversions - someone searches on Google, comes to the site, clicks on an event, fills out the form, and finishes the purchase. Page views and such would be nice, but conversions is the part that is the must. And it's Drupal, not WP. I thought I had that in the text, but I guess not.

Comment: Hi Jenni, Just to confirm - Do you or do you not have Google Analytics setup and running on your Drupal site? If so, is it covering your CiviCRM pages - becuase it should.

We use behavior to track conversions - in the image I uploaded I can see that 5 people went to the event page, 2 people clicked to register, 1 person actually registered. Its a manual process but it works for us. If you want to use the conversions section of google analytics, you need a destination URL - you could use your registration page as the destination and just compare that to who registered on your website.

Comment: We do have GA set up on our Drupal site. But it's obviously not talking to the Civi pages correctly since it will show that 2 people signed up when in fact more than a dozen did. See, that's the issue - a lack of destination URL. With most software, you can give it an end URL and it looks to see who visited the site and then who made it all the way to the final page (meaning they registered).

Answer (score 0):

The Google Summer of Code project mentioned in Kurund's answer has been updated and improved upon by members of the community, it's now called the [Webtracking](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/webtracking) extension.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks for that update! Going to check it out now. :)